# createPresignedPost not working (error 400)

Tags: amazon-web-services, forms, amazon-s3, post, aws-sdk-js

I am trying to upload .mp3 files to my bucket via presignedPost (so I can set maximum content-size). I keep getting an error 400 with no real error content. I've looked at AWS logs, and there's no real error message, and the error I get from the browser is a generic error 400 (bad request). Here is the code.

My presign code:

```
import { createPresignedPost } from '@aws-sdk/s3-presigned-post'
import { S3Client } from '@aws-sdk/client-s3'
import { v4 as uuid } from 'uuid'

// Env varas
import { AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY } from '$env/static/private'

const s3 = new S3Client({ 
  region: 'us-east-2',
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
  } 
})

const BUCKET = 'thundermp3-songs'

/** @type {import('./$types').PageServerData} */
export const GET = async ({ request, url }: { request: Request, url: string }) => {
  // Generate a presigned url
  try {
    console.log('envs: ', AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    const key = uuid() + '.mp3'
    const res = await createPresignedPost(s3, {
      Bucket: BUCKET,
      Conditions: [
        ['content-length-range', 0, 1048576 * 16], // up to 16MB
        ['starts-with', '$Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data']
      ],
      Expires: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 7 days
      Fields: {
        file: ''
      },
      Key: key
    })
    console.log(res)
    const { url: presignedUrl, fields } = res
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ fields, key, presignedUrl }), { status: 201 })
  } catch(e) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ message: `Error: ${e}` }), { status: 500 })
  }
}
```

My submit code (All of the data is there. No undefined or bad data):

```
 const handleUpload = async () => {
    if (files.accepted.length === 0) return
    uploading = true
    try {
      // Get a presigned url from api/presign
      const presignedUrl = await fetch('/api/presign', {
        method: 'GET',
      })
      const presignedRes = await presignedUrl.json()
      
      const file = new File([files.accepted[0]], presignedRes.fields.key, { type: files.accepted[0].type })
      const formData = new FormData()
      Object.entries(presignedRes.fields).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        if (value instanceof Blob) formData.set(key, value)
        else if (typeof value === 'string') formData.set(key, value)
      })
      formData.set('file', file)
      const res = await fetch(presignedRes.presignedUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': `multipart/form-data`,
        }
      })

      console.log(res)

      const data = await res.json()
      console.log('returned data from upload: ', data)
    } catch(e) {
      console.error('upload error: ', e)
    } finally {
      uploading = false
      handleClear()
    }
  }
```

Comment: I have the same issue and am getting the following error along with status 400: <Error>
<Code>InvalidPolicyDocument</Code>
<Message>
Invalid Policy: Invalid Simple-Condition: Simple-Conditions must have exactly one property specified.
</Message>